# ModelMapper: Map object which has nested collection to flat object

Tags: java, mapper, modelmapper

I have a class with a nested list and I want to map this object into list of flat objects using `ModelMapper`.

```
public class A {
  private String str;
  private String str2;
  private List<B> blist;

  // Setters and getters
}

public class B {
  private String str3;
  private String str4;

  // Setters and getters
}

public class C {
  private String str;
  private String str2;
  private String str3;
  private String str4;

  // Setters and getters
}
```

I want to convert an object of class `A` into a list of objects of class `C`